# Getting div width and height from jquery if that div used percentage itself

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the div size in px while itself it set to 100% as width & height.

But CDT output gives:
**Width = 437px and Height=439**
But when I try to inspect that div tag CDT display **width = 420 and height = 422px** (as seen in image)

Why is that happen when I used

```
var divWidth = $('.divhandler').width();
var divHeight = $('.divhandler').height();
```

[image]

```js
  function getImageDimensions(path, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      callback({
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height
      });
    }
    img.src = path;
  }
  var imgWidth;
  var imgHeight;

  function DoReset(_width, _height) {
    imgWidth = _width;
    imgHeight = _height;
    console.log("IMG Width:" + imgWidth);
    console.log("IMG Height:" + imgHeight);
    //get div 
    var divWidth = $('.divhandler').width();
    var divHeight = $('.divhandler').height();
    console.log("DIV Width:" + divWidth);
    console.log("DIV Height:" + divHeight);
    var ratioCalc;
    var newImageHeight;
    var newImageWidth;
    if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
      if (divWidth > imgWidth) {
        ratioCalc = imgWidth / imgHeight;
        newImageHeight = divHeight * ratioCalc;
        newImageWidth = (imgWidth / imgHeight) * newImageHeight;
        $('.imghandler').css('width', newImageHeight + 'px');
        console.log("1");
      } else {
        ratioCalc = imgHeight / imgWidth;
        newImageHeight = divWidth * ratioCalc;
        $('.imghandler').css('height', newImageHeight + 'px');
        console.log("2");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("2");
    }
  }
  getImageDimensions("http://www.dailymobile.net/wp-content/uploads/wallpapers/landscape-wallpapers-320x240/landscape-wallpapers-320x240-03.jpg", function(data) {
    imgWidth = data.width;
    imgHeight = data.height;
    DoReset(data.width, data.height);
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    getImageDimensions("cgihandle.jpg", function(data) {
      imgWidth = data.width;
      imgHeight = data.height;
      DoReset(imgWidth, imgHeight);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divhandler" style="width:100%;height:100%;background:#ccc"> <img src="http://www.dailymobile.net/wp-content/uploads/wallpapers/landscape-wallpapers-320x240/landscape-wallpapers-320x240-03.jpg" class="imghandler" /> </div>
```

Comment: It because of the margin and padding to your div

Comment: But when I use CDT console and type this `$('.divhandler').width();` it will show the correct size

Answer (score 0):

During the mouse hover , the total size of the div is shown to you in CDT , along with the padding and border as shown in the image. Your actual div size is 437x439 but the increase is due to the padding around it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.height()` and `.width()` Don't include borders, paddings and margins. If you want those included in width calc, use `.outerHeight()` and `.outerWidth()`

---

http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Comment: But when I use CDT console and type this `$('.divhandler').width();` it will show the correct size.